# "Status Code:200 OK (from ServiceWorker)" in Chrome Network DevTools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http-headers, service-worker

I am familiar with http status codes, but recently I saw a strange line in my chrome debugger. Instead of ordinary `Status Code:200 OK` I saw the following: `Status Code:200 OK (from ServiceWorker)`.

[image]

My guess is that this just tells me that ServiceWorker is somehow responsible for accessing this document, but this is just random guess. Can anyone authoritatively (without guesses, with links to respected resources) tell me what does this mean and what are the implications?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a common source of confusion, so I wanted to go into a bit more detail.

I have a full working demo in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/7547c69a0780f7782423), and you can view a [live version of it](https://rawgit.com/jeffposnick/7547c69a0780f7782423/raw/c64d054efe60fea88b85b601245bd7157ecdc1e8/index.html) thanks to RawGit.

Here's the relevant portion of the service worker code inline, for illustrative purposes:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.url.endsWith('one.js')) {
    // Requests for one.js will result in the SW firing off a fetch() request,
    // which will be reflected in the DevTools Network panel.
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
  } else if (event.request.url.endsWith('two.js')) {
    // Requests for two.js will result in the SW constructing a new Response object,
    // so there won't be an additional network request in the DevTools Network panel.
    event.respondWith(new Response('// no-op'));
  }

  // Requests for anything else won't trigger event.respondWith(), so there won't be
  // any SW interaction reflected in the DevTools Network panel.
});
```

And here's what a filtered version of the Network panel looks like in Chrome 48 when that service worker is in control of a page, and requests are made for `one.js`, `two.js`, and `three.js`:

[image: Chrome DevTools Network panel]

Our service worker's `fetch` handler will do one of three things:

- If it's a request for `one.js`, it will fire off a `fetch()` request for the same URL, and then call `event.respondWith()` using that response. The first `one.js` entry in the screenshot, the one with "(from ServiceWorker)" in the "Size" column, is there by virtue of the fact that we called `event.respondWith()` inside the `fetch` handler. The second `one.js` entry in the screenshot, the one with the little gear icon next to it and "(from cache)" in the "Size" column, represents that `fetch()` request that was made inside the service worker while responding to the event. Since the actual `one.js` file was already in the HTTP cache at the point I took this screenshot, you see "(from cache)", but if the HTTP cache didn't have that response already, you would see an actual network request along with the response size.
- If it's a request for `two.js`, it will handle the request by constructing a new `Response` object "from thin air". (Yes, you can do that!) In this case, we are calling `event.respondWith()`, so there's an entry for `two.js` with "(from ServiceWorker)" in the "Size" column. But unlike with `one.js`, we're not using `fetch()` to populate the response, so there's no additional entry in the Network panel for `two.js`.
- Finally, if it's a request for `three.js`, our service worker's `fetch` event handler won't actually call `event.respondWith()`. From the perspective of the page, and also from the perspective of the Network panel, there's no service worker involvement with that request, which is why there's just a "(from cache)" rather than "(from ServiceWorker)" in the "Size" column.

Comment: All the entries with the gear icon have the value “Other” in the Initiator column. Maybe a more descriptive value would make more sense?

Comment: @JeffPosnick the problem arises when you want to check the cache. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker#cache_falling_back_to_the_network  With this suggested method every request is listed as "from service worker" on the chrome tab, even those delegated to the network. How does one ensure true network requests are shown correctly in this scenario?

Comment: What does the gear icon mean?

Comment: I found the answer to my question about what the gear icon means on the google debugging service workers page (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/), which also references this stackoverflow question.  "The gear icon signifies that these requests came from the Service Worker itself. Specifically, these are the requests being made by the Service Worker's install handler to populate the offline cache."

Comment: @Jeff Posnick Hello, could you check this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117929/workbox-service-worker-maxageseconds-query

Answer (score 5):

A service worker is a script that is run by your browser in the background. So Status Code:200 OK (from ServiceWorker) mean that “OK” success code, for GET or HEAD request and this status come from ServiceWorker.

You can read this link to understand more about this.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/

Comment: What implications will it have?

Answer (score 4):

This is normal . To avoid confusion arising out by `200` for every request. Its showing that the request is a `SUCCESS` but `service-worker` has responded for the resource / request instead of `network/server`

Answer (score 0):

My understanding...: The browser has had(stored) service worker for the domain requested the previous time to effectively serve response for newer http requests about status hence contributing to reducing(making faster) the time to complete request-response cycle.