# ServiceWorker is not fetching all requests

Tags: requirejs, service-worker

I'm playing around with ServiceWorkers. 
In the current case I'm trying an example worker: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/prefetch/service-worker.js

After running it in my context (complex framework with jquery and require) only small part of the request are going through the ServiceWorker.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what \`Status Code:200 OK (from ServiceWorker)\` means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590378/what-status-code200-ok-from-serviceworker-means)

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33655173/385997 applies to your question as well.

Comment: The answer in this question is helpful but is not a complete answer for my question.