# Why size display (from serviceworker) for post method?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, service-worker

Why size column displays

> (from ServiceWorker)

for post method ?

I'm using angular cli with service worker. As far as I know post should not go throw service worker.

[image]

Comment: Best guess: service workers are used to proxy *all* network access once you have one installed.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33655173/385997