# Workbox images fetch problem to other Url

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using workbox to fetch images. Images are fetching successfully. but Workbox fetches  image file two times.When I check in console
1. same image fetch sucessfully
2. same image throw an error failed to fetch.

and one more erroe (in promise): failed to fetch

My console show::

workbox Router is responding to: https://www.url.com/images/icon_youtube.png

uncaught(in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

workbox Network request for 'https://www.url.com/images/icon_youtube.png' threw an error TypeError:: Failed to fetch

Comment: The multiple entries might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33655173/385997 If you're currently offline, then one entry with a Gear icon would be an error (since the network request fails) and the other would be a success (since it's a cached response from the SW).