# ServiceWorker fetch-complete event

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker

Reasone, I am using serviceWorker - is to check the time until cookie ends. Cookie expiration is set to 60 minutes on request.

I built 2 versions of the fetch listener on serviceWorker

This version resets time counter on on the client (by sending a message to it by `channel.postMessage`. But it sends the trigger on request (not after response).

```js
self.addEventListener( "fetch", event => {
    channel.postMessage(true);
});
```

The second version creates new fetch call, gets the response, triggers client, and then returns the response.

```js
self.addEventListener( "fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
        const response = await fetch(event.request);
        channel.postMessage(true);
        return response;
    })());
});
```

In this situation - second option would be more accurate in terms of time. But this creates those duplicate network requests, if looking at network tab in the developer tools
[image: duplicate requests]

Is it somehow possible, to let the fetch do it's thing, let it complete, and get the response without creating new fetch call? I am not interested in any sort of serviceWorker for caching (100% of the use cases for fetch event in examples are for caching...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one network call being made in this scenario, although Chrome's DevTools Network panel might be a bit confusing and imply otherwise. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33655173/385997) explains what you're seeing in more detail.

If the only thing you want to do in your `fetch` handler is call `channel.postMessage()`, then I would recommend not calling `event.respondWith()`. If you have another `fetch` handler registered after your first one, that handler will get its own chance to respond. If none of your `fetch` handlers call `event.respondWith()`, then it will effectively be a no-op from a networking perspective.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Optional: you might want to check for some criteria
  // before calling channel.postMessage().
  if (event.request.url === '...') {
    channel.postMessage(true);
  }
});
```